# Hyper-V Server - Can't UnJoin An Orphaned Domain

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I have a [Hyper-V](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2010/05/03/Why-I-hate-Hyper_2D00_V-_2800_aka-DyperV_2900_.aspx) host running on a Windows 2008 server that does not have a desktop GUI.

This server is currently joined to a domain that no longer exists and there are no domain controller for that old domain still on the network.

Using a local admin account, at the windows command prompt, I'm trying to unjoin from the non existing domain.

I've tried this command:

```
netdom remove /d:DomainThatNoLongerExist.COM HYPERVComputerName
```

I get this:

```
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The command failed to complete successfully.
```

Instead of "unjoining first", I've tried just joining to the new existing domain, but each time I try, it says it is already joined, but it really isn't already joined; because the name of the new domain is a subdomain of the previous domain, it assumes it is already joined, and that false presumption is causing me a lot trouble.

So, can someone please tell me how I can un-join this non-longer-existing domain?

BTW, this especially important because I can't access any of the currently running virtual machines via Hyper-V manager because it automatically authenticates using the client's windows-login-credentials which are for another domain than the hyper-v host's non-existing domain. The only access I have is a local admin account, and I cannot figure out how to use those credentials in Hyper-V Manager from a remote machine (and I know no way to launch Hyper-V Manager on the Host machine after logging in as a local admin).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/783802df-6c59-4665-9860-7e2d0720db4a/), which enlightened me to the /force parameter. The command that ultimately worked was:

```
netdom remove /d:DomainThatNoLongerExist.COM HYPERVComputerName /FORCE
```