# Joining Workgroup using powershell fails if domain controller cannot be reached

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows machine that has been cloned and to keep it from overwriting DNS entries it has only port 3389 enabled. What I am currently doing is using the GUI to join a workgroup and then renaming the computer before re-joining the domain. This works when done through the GUI but when done via Powershell it fails to leave domain and join workgroup.

I was attempting to use:

```
Add-Computer -WorkGroupName MyWorkGroup
```

However this gives the error:

```
 Add-Computer : Failed to unjoin computer from domain with the following error message: The
specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

I though perhaps running Powershell as the local Administrator might work, but that encountered the same error. I though maybe using the cached domain admin account might work, but also get the same error. I thought maybe specifying any or all of the Credential/LocalCredential/UnjoinDomainCredential parameters might help but that yielded no luck either.

It seems like there has to be a way to do this through Powershell that I am overlooking. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but can you maybe disjoin it before you leave the domain?

Comment: @Zoredache Unfortunately I cannot disjoin it first. The clone is created from a backup of a production system.

Comment: I haven't used that command in that type of situation, but have you tried passing a `-force`?  Worst case, it may be that you could use netdom.  https://serverfault.com/questions/511317/hyper-v-server-cant-unjoin-an-orphaned-domain

Comment: @Zoredache -force did not work but the netdom command did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure if this works, but you may want to give it a try by using:

```
Remove-Computer -ComputerName "Server01" -UnjoinDomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -WorkgroupName "Local" -Restart -Force
```

[Microsoft Documentation : Remove-Computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-computer?view=powershell-5.1)